# Edit Image of Post With ploymorphic relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Hy all,

I need to update the picture of a article, all it's fine for updating post but my question it's how to update the image of this post with my polymorphic relation.

i have a table Images with imageable_id imageable_type path .

in my Post controller update function i have

```
public function update($id)
{
    $inputs = Input::all();

    $rules =array(
        'name'=>'required|min:5',
        'description'=>'required|min:10',
    );

    $validation = Validator::make($inputs,$rules);

    if($validation->fails()){
        return Redirect::to('posts/'.Input::get('id').'/edit')->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validation)
            ->with('alert_error','Veuillez corriger les érreurs SVP');
    }

    if(Input::hasFile('mediafile')){
        $file = Input::file('mediafile');
        $name = date('Ymd') . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file = $file->move('img/uploads/', $name);

        $path = $file->getRealPath();

        //take the path only at the img not totally
        $pos = strpos($path,'/img/');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $path = substr($path, $pos + 1);
        }
        $input['file'] = $path;

        $post=Post::find(Input::get('id'));
        $post->name        = e(Input::get('name'));
        $post->description = e(Input::get('description'));
        $post->category_id = e(Input::get('categories'));
        $post->tag_id     = e(Input::get('tag'));
        $post->rating     = e(Input::get('rating'));
        $post->content     = Input::get('content');
        $post->is_online   = e(Input::get('online'));
        $post->images->path = e(Input::get('mediafile'));

        $post->save();

    }

}
```

My model Post

```
public function images(){

return $this->morphMany('Image','imageable');
}
```

So i wish update only the path of my image in my table Image when i submit my form to show the new picture of post.

Thank's for help

Answer (score 0):

The morphMany will return a collection of Images, so when you run $post->images->path you're setting the path attribute on the collection not on an image model. If a Post is only meant to have one image, change it to a morphOne or alternatively you will have to identify the image model you wish to update from the collection.

Comment: i'm nopt sure to understand how to proceed foir update with the morphone. the best practice is just for edit image of the post build a new function in my post model with the morphone? thank's

Comment: The difference between morphOne and morphMany is based on the relationship between your models. In your Post model you specify that one post has many images, however in your Post controller you are using post->image as though one post has one image. If its a one to one relationship, just update the morphMany to morphOne - or alternatively if it's meant to be a one to many realtionship, post->images will return a collection. If that's the case, you will have to figure out which image you wish to update. Hope that helps (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)